# Rx in .Net 3.5 not Asynchronous?

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am playing with Rx in .Net3.5SP1 and trying the [101 Rx Samples](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc1).  I am trying the first sample (Start - Run Code Asynchronously) but it doesn't seem to actually run asynchronously.  For example,

```
        Console.WriteLine("[Creating]");
        var o = Observable.Start(() => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calculating..."); 
            Thread.Sleep(3000); 
            Console.WriteLine("Done."); 
        });
        Console.WriteLine("[Created]");
        Console.WriteLine("[Starting]");
        o.First();   // subscribe and wait for completion of background operation
        Console.WriteLine("[Started]");
```

Outputs

```
[Creating]
[Created]
[Starting]
Calculating...
    <...3 Second Wait...>
Done.
[Started]
```

Is there an explanation for this?  Am I doing something wrong?  Is this expected behaviour?

UPDATE

I would have thought it would have said

```
[Creating] 
[Created] 
[Starting] 
Calculating... 
[Started] 
    <...3 Second Wait...> 
Done.
```

But the main thread is blocked while the supposedly Asynch call happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks reasonably expected to me.

If you put a `Thread.Sleep` call between "Created" and "Starting" I think you'll see the "Calculating" line appear, showing that it's doing work while the main thread is running. That's the way in which it's asynchronous.

If you're concerned because `First()` returns the value itself, rather than giving a sort of "future" value you can consult later, that's a different matter - and I have two blog posts for you to read: [part 1](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/16/first-encounters-with-reactive-extensions.aspx); [part 2](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/19/linq-to-rx-second-impressions.aspx). I *think* you want the `Prune` method, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: No that's not the issue... the issue is the sequence of events.  I would have thought it would have said

[Creating]
[Created]
[Starting]
Calculating...
[Started]
    <...3 Second Wait...>
Done.
 
But the main thread is blocked while the supposedly Asynch call happens...

Comment: @kouPhax: The First() method has to *return* the value though, doesn't it? (Admittedly the value is just `Unit` in this case, but still...) This means it can't complete until *after* the calculation has finished. Basically the calculation *is* going on asynchronously, but the First() call waits for it to complete. The comment explicitly says that: "// subscribe and wait for completion of background operation"

Answer (score 1):

The line `// subscribe and wait for completion of background operation` says that it waits for the background operation to complete. So you wouldn't expect the code following that line (`Console.WriteLine("[Started]");`) to run until the the operation is completed, right?

Answer (score 1):

First is blocking ... Subscribe is what you want:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args) {

        Console.WriteLine("[Creating]");
        var o = Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calculating...");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

        });
        Console.WriteLine("[Created]");
        Console.WriteLine("[Starting]");

        o.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Done."));   // subscribe and wait for completion of background operation 

        Console.WriteLine("[Started]");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```